# Script or util to remove old backups

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, dos

I'm creating a backup strategy for a sharepoint server I'm setting up.

Have got a backup running daily.

In the long term I'd like to keep:

```
* Daily backups for the last week.
* Weekly backups for the last month.
* Monthly backups for the last year.
* Yearly backups.
```

If I was writing in bash/cygwin I would find it fairly easy to write a script to purge backups that are not required by this strategy. However I would rather not have to install cygwin, I'd rather do it with native DOS scripting, or some other specialized tool.

My DOS scripting skills are very primitive, so I was wondering if anyone else had a similar script/util I could use.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to achieve a rather compelx backup procedure. Or you could write the script in **Python** or another executable scripting language.

[PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) can be convoluted at first, but it's basically Batch Scripts **on crack** with access to the .NET Runtime.

---

*Note: PowerShell I believe is only availiable on 2003, Vista, Windows 7 (I know it comes with them, at least, it **may** work with XP/2000, but im not sure). Python can be installed on prettymuch anything.*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a bash script to do this.  run-backup-maintenance.sh

Usage example:  run-backup-maintenance.sh d7w4m12y10 /cygdrive/d/backup ".*.tar"

NOTE: All daily backups must be written to: /cygdrive/d/backup/daily

If run with the parameter d7w4m12y10, this script ensures that over time:

```
/cygdrive/d/backup/daily    will contain daily backups for the last 7 days
/cygdrive/d/backup/weekly   will contain weekly backups for the last 4 weeks
/cygdrive/d/backup/monthly  will contain monthly backups for the last 12 months
/cygdrive/d/backup/yearly   will contain yearly backups for the last 10 years
```

Enjoy!

```
#!/bin/bash
die () {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

[ "$#" -eq 3 ] || die "Usage run-backup.sh <options> <backupDir> <artefact>."$'\n'"3 arguments required, $# provided."$'\n'"Options should be given as d#w#m#y#, where # is a number denoting how long to keep the specified backup period."$'\n'"e.g. d7w4m12y10 says that backup will keep: 7 daily backups, 4 weekly backups, 12 monthly backups and 10 yearly backups."

#################################
#PROCESS PARAMETERS
backupDir=$2
artefactPattern=$3

regex="d\([0-9]*\)w\([0-9]*\)m\([0-9]*\)y\([0-9]*\)"
days=`echo $1 | sed "s/$regex/\1/g"`
weeks=`echo $1 | sed "s/$regex/\2/g"`
months=`echo $1 | sed "s/$regex/\3/g"`
years=`echo $1 | sed "s/$regex/\4/g"`

echo "Running backup in folder $backupDir against artefacts matching $artefactPattern keeping: $days days, $weeks weeks, $months months, $years years"

#################################
#YEARLY

if [ $years -ne 0 ]; then
    #Check that the yearly folder has a backup for the last 365 days
    fileListing=`find $backupDir/yearly -mtime -364 | grep "$artefactPattern"`
    if [ "$fileListing" == "" ]; then
        echo 'No files from last 365 days found, taking most recent daily backup...'
        cd $backupDir/daily/
        ls -t1 | grep "$artefactPattern" | head -n1 | xargs -t -I {} cp -r {} ../yearly/
        cd ../..
    else
        echo 'Yearly backup found, no copying required...'
    fi

    #Remove yearly backups older than x years
    find $backupDir/yearly -mtime +$(((years*365)-1)) | grep "$artefactPattern" | xargs rm -rf
fi

#################################
#MONTHLY

if [ $months -ne 0 ]; then
    #Check that the weekly folder has a backup for the last 30 days
    fileListing=`find $backupDir/monthly -mtime -29 | grep "$artefactPattern"`
    if [ "$fileListing" == "" ]; then
        echo 'No files from last 30 days found, taking most recent daily backup...'
        cd $backupDir/daily/
        ls -t1 | grep "$artefactPattern" | head -n1 | xargs -t -I {} cp -r {} ../monthly/
        cd ../..
    else
        echo 'Monthly backup found, no copying required...'
    fi

    #Remove monthly backups older than x months
    find $backupDir/monthly -mtime +$(((months*30)-1)) | grep "$artefactPattern" | xargs rm -rf
fi

#################################
#WEEKLY

if [ $weeks -ne 0 ]; then
    #Check that the weekly folder has a backup for the last 7 days
    fileListing=`find $backupDir/weekly -mtime -6 | grep "$artefactPattern"`
    if [ "$fileListing" == "" ]; then
        echo 'No files from last 7 days found, taking most recent daily backup...'
        cd $backupDir/daily/
        ls -t1 | grep "$artefactPattern" | head -n1 | xargs -t -I {} cp -r {} ../weekly/
        cd ../..
    else
        echo 'Weekly backup found, no copying required...'
    fi

    #Remove weekly backups older than X days
    find $backupDir/weekly -mtime +$(((weeks*7)-1)) | grep "$artefactPattern" | xargs rm -rf
fi

#################################
#DAILY

if [ $days -ne 0 ]; then
    #Remove daily backups older than X days
    find $backupDir/daily -mtime +$((days-1)) | grep "$artefactPattern" | xargs rm -rf
else
    find $backupDir/daily | grep "$artefactPattern" | xargs rm -rf
fi
```